# Adding both the title and image to an NSStatusItem

Tags: nsimageview, nsstatusitem, nsstatusbar

I've been trying to figure out how to add both text and an image to an NSStatusItem. Here is a mockup of what i'm trying to do:

http://cl.ly/GjTO

I've tried using the statusIetm.view and adding a subview, I've tried setting both the title and image property for fun even though I know that doesn't work. 'm not trying to add a a custom window the the Status Item, but the temperature and condition icon found in the first image. If anyone has any idea, I'd love to hear them.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NSStatusItem Button Title to the Right of the Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31250311/nsstatusitem-button-title-to-the-right-of-the-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a custom NSView and setting it with 
    [statusItem setView:myCustomView];

Comment: I totally forgot about that method. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 2):

```
statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
NSImage *statusImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"]; // must be 19x19 max
[statusItem setImage:statusImage];
NSImage *altStatusImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
[statusItem setAlternateImage:altStatusImage];
[statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
[statusItem setAttributedTitle:attrString];
[statusItem setTitle:@"Loading..."];
[statusItem setMenu:statusMenu];
```

Comment: A better icon should be 38 x 38 pixels max with 144 ppi resolution

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without a custom view like this:

```swift
button.imagePosition = NSControl.ImagePosition.imageLeft
```

*Thanks to [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56368854/486182)*