# NSStatusItem Button Title to the Right of the Image

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsstatusitem

I want an `NSStatusItem`’s button’s title to appear to the right of its image. Here’s an example, this is the OS X VPN menubar app:

[image: Example]

If I set either the title or image for my `NSStatusItem`’s button, they render correctly. However if I set *both*, they get superimposed and are horizontally center-aligned.

Is there a way to achieve the side-by-side placement without creating a custom `UIView`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has to do with a change in Yosemite, which deprecated `setTitle:` and `setImage:` on `NSStatusItem`. The documentation isn't super-helpful for what to do instead, however.

I’ve found that you have to set the title and the image on the `button` property of the `NSStatusItem`. That’s how I was getting the behaviour described above, with the title and the image centred over each other.

The solution is simple but not immediately apparent. NSStatusBarItem responds to the `setImagePosition:` method of `NSButton`. Here’s the code that fixed my issue:

```
self.statusItem.button.image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"StatusBarIcon"];
self.statusItem.button.imagePosition = NSImageLeft;
```

Having done this, setting `self.statusItem.button.title` positions the items correctly.

Comment: do you know if this has changed recently or in swift? I have this same issue, but when I've tried 
      `self.statusItem.button.imagePosition = NSImageLeft` I get 'Use of unresolved identifier 'NSImageLeft''

Comment: I also tried the values listed for `NSCellImagePosition` but no dice there either https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSCellImagePosition

Comment: figured it out below

Answer (score 3):

based on http://tinkker.io/swift/2015/11/10/nsstatusitem.html, in Swift it looks like `button.imagePosition = NSCellImagePosition.ImageLeft` does it

Answer (score 3):

use

```
button.imagePosition = NSControl.ImagePosition.imageLeft
```