# Display an icon and text on NSStatusBar for macOS using Swift

Tags: swift, macos, statusbar, nsstatusbar

I would like to display an icon and some texts to its right on a NSStatusBar.

The code I'm using, as seen below, displays the icon and the text overlapping.

This is an example of I'm trying to emulate:

[image: status bar example]

And here's my current code for reference:

```
let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength:NSStatusItem.variableLength)
var preferencesWindow: NSWindowController?

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    if let button = statusItem.button {
        button.image = NSImage(named:NSImage.Name("StatusBarButtonImage"))
        button.title = "..."
    }
    initMenu()
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `button.imagePosition`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NSStatusItem Button Title to the Right of the Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31250311/nsstatusitem-button-title-to-the-right-of-the-image)

Comment: @Willeke it does